# Amazon PutObjectRequest for large files throws error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting an error while uploading large files more than 50 MB using

> **PUTObjectRequest** . It throws an error **unable to write data to the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed
>   by the remote host.**

I am using federated user for this putobjectrequest. 
Please help me out to solve this issue.

I am sending multiple files parallel using task as

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{

PutObjectRequest req=new PutObjectRequest()

{

bucketName=_bucketName,

key=fileKey,

FilePath=demoPath

};

PutObjectResponse resp= client.PurObjectRequest(req);

}

);
```

Comment: Is it possible, since you are uploading in parallel, that you are overwhelming your Internet connection with too much traffic, causing timeouts?  First suggestion would be to try only one large file in isolation and see if the problem persists.

Comment: i tried single file also but response is same :( ERROR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in aws sdk version i was using 2.3.20

Now i am using aws sdk version 2.3.40 and it is working fine. Basically it was error due to time difference between client machine and server fixed in the updated aws sdk dll

Comment: if any one want to know the issue in details. I am happy to answer,